# Waitlist feature and price set issue

Tags: civievent, price-sets, participants, status, waitlist

When testing the waitlist feature for an event the ticket selections are greyed out and listed as sold out.

The waitlist is dependent on the status and in my test scenario the max number of participants is 3. In my dashboard I have two participants that are attending, one participant that I changed the status to Registered but then canceled, and finally one participant that has a status pending from waitlist.

When looking at my dashboard everything is displayed correctly: I have two registered guests and again my max count is 3. When I go to complete the registration for my waitlisted guest all of the ticket options are greyed out and listed as sold out even though I have room for one more participant to register.

- Does the price set option override the status if the ticket selection is counted towards the max participant number?

  - The status for my cancelled guest is class negative and is counted. (I did test having it not counted as well)

How do I fix this waitlist issue?